# The connection could not be opened. RCRI0030 - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem with Crystal reports, because when I try to see the preview of a report I get the following error:

The connection could not be opened. RCRI0030(...).rpt

I tried to install an administrator to view them but I haven't succeeded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to install the next one.

Currently, the download link is
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402